# The error in Color picker for Sublime Text3

Tags: sublimetext

*Colors* selector box in program *Sublime Text*, as implemented in this editor:

[image]

I'm install the package *Colopicker* in *ST3*, when I press **ctrl+shift+c**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 549, in run_
    return self.run(edit)
  File "sublimecp in C:\Users\konst\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\ColorPicker.sublime-package", line 172, in run
  File "sublimecp in C:\Users\konst\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\ColorPicker.sublime-package", line 240, in pick_win
  File "X/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
  File "X/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) for a plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

The VisualColorPicker.dll doesn't have an x64 bit version, we can use a proxy exe wrapper. It should work properly.

The ansewer read https://github.com/weslly/ColorPicker/pull/44